# Call a method of an Activity from another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two `Activities` A and B. B has a method `searchDevices`. I want to access that method from A 's `onCreate` method. How can I do it with `Intent`?
I tried this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    try{


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MY_UUID= UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");    


    //Function enbling Bluetooth
    enableBluetooth();

    ///Function to initialize components
    init();


    //Calling AvailableDevices class's method searchDevice to get                AvailableDevices
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,AvailableDevices.class);
    int x=10;
    intent.putExtra("A", x);

    }catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a base activity that both `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` extends and put searchDevices() method in it.

For ex:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

public void searchDevices(){

}

}


public class ActivityB extends BaseActivity{
onCreate..
{
  ...
  searchDevices();
}
}


public class ActivityA extends BaseActivity{
onCreate..
{
  ...
  searchDevices();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if `ActivityA` is in a class called `class1` make a method in class1 like this

```
public static void method1(){
}
```

then in activity 2 call the method by doing this `ActivityA.method1()`

Comment: You absolutely cannot do this. You cannot instantiate an `Activity` with `new`. This is just wrong. Android instantiates activities itself and sets up a lot of infrastructure (like the `Context`) when it does that. An `Activity` isn't just some random Java class. How does an answer like this get 3 upvotes??

Comment: @DavidWasser if you are just instantiating it to get a method from it then it works fine. Its not like I'm telling him to start a new intent with it...

Comment: Well, no. It doesn't "just work". It depends a lot on what the method does. For example, if the method you are calling does anything that requires the `Context` (or `this`), it will fail. This is just a bad idea because it will eventually get you into trouble. You should never ever instantiate Android components (`Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `ContentProvider`) with `new`.

Comment: @DavidWasser is that better?

Comment: In general, static methods in activities are not a good approach (bad architecture). If you have a static method that is unrelated to the Activity, it should go into a generic utilities class, and not in the Activity itself. If the method uses or modifies any fields in the Activity, then it can't be static anyway. Sorry, this is the wrong approach. Other answers are better.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use [StartActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

As per my understanding You can start AvailableDevices Activity for result with Intent having extra data and call searchDevice to get AvailableDevices and return the result to calling Activity.

[Edit]

In Class A

```
//Calling AvailableDevices class's method searchDevice to get AvailableDevices
Intent intent=new Intent(this,AvailableDevices.class);
int x=10;
intent.putExtra("A", x);
startActivityForResult(intent , searchDevicesRequestCode); //searchDevicesRequestCode = 100
```

Also override onActivityResult()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == searchDevicesRequestCode) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Manipulate searchDevicesResult from Intent data
        }
    }
}
```

In Class B

```
@override    
onCreate()
{
    //call searchDevices()
    String result = searchDevices(); // save result to send in any form
    // Create intent to deliver some kind of result data
    Intent intentResult = new Intent("RESULT_ACTION");
    intentResult.putExtra("key",result);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intentResult);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Plz explain how to call method using intent i am quite new in android i want a n example code

Comment: Its not simple method call. Its just another way to work around. You can call  startActivityForResult() with intent and implement onActivityResult() in calling activity to wait for result. Please read [http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) for details.